# solvability of an elementary functional equation

Tags: functional-equations

Is there some other way to characterize the functions $f:\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$  which are expressible as
$$f(x,y)=g(x)+g(y)-g(x+y)$$
for some $g:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$?

**Easy facts:** (1) $f$ must satisfy $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ and $f(x,0)=g(0)$ for all $x$. (2) Not all functions $f$ are expressible, since for $x,y\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ the number of choices of $f(x,y)$ the left grows quadratically in $n$ and the number of possible values of $g$ on which they depend, grows just linearly.

Comment: $f(x,0)=g(0)$, not $0$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form

Comment: Here is a necessary condition: $$f(x,y+z)+f(y,z)=f(y,x+z)+f(x,z).$$ Could it be sufficient ?


Comment: @ chris: yes, that's right. I will edit the post.

Comment: @ steve and denis: 
Thanks Steve, that's an interesting link! In fact my original motivation was apparently different: 

One has a family of operators $I_x$ with $I_x\circ I_y=F(x,y) I_{x+y}, F>0$, I wanted to know when can I normalize the whole family cancelling away the $F$-factor. 

The answer of Denis means that *associativity* of the composition is the requirement! I find that very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient condition is that 
$$f(x,y+z)+f(y,z)=f(y,x+z)+f(x,z),\qquad\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb Z.\qquad (1)$$
On the one hand, this is obviously necessary. On the other hand, the function $g$, if it exists, is given by
$$g(k)=kg(1)-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f(j,1).$$
Then $g$ is suitable if and only if
$$f(k,\ell)=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f(j,1)-\sum_{j=\ell}^{k+\ell-1}f(j,1),\qquad k,\ell\in\mathbb Z.$$
There remains to check that these relations are consequences of (1).

Note that (1) contains the fact that $x\mapsto f(x,0)$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I think that this settles the question.

Answer (score 5):

This is secretly a question about [group cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology).  Suppose we want to compute $\operatorname{Ext}^*_{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ when $G=\langle g \rangle$ is infinite cyclic and the action on the integers is trivial.  We can easily write down a free resolution

$$ 0 \to \mathbb{Z}G(g-1) \to \mathbb{Z}G \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0 $$

and work it out from there: in particular it's clear that $\operatorname{Ext}^n$ vanishes for $n>1$.  But we could also try using the bar resolution.  On writing this down and applying $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}G} ( -, \mathbb{Z})$ you find that the ext groups are given by the cohomology of the following cocomplex:

$$ \hom_{\mathbb{Z}G} (\mathbb{Z}G, \mathbb{Z}) \to \hom_{\mathbb{Z}G} (\bigoplus_{g \in G} \mathbb{Z}G[g], \mathbb{Z}) \to \hom_{\mathbb{Z}G} (\bigoplus_{g,h \in G} \mathbb{Z}G[g|h],\mathbb{Z}) \to \ldots $$

Of course, $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}G} (\bigoplus_{g \in G} \mathbb{Z}G[g], \mathbb{Z})$ can be identified with the set of maps of sets $G \to \mathbb{Z}$ and so on.  On doing this we get that $\operatorname{Ext}^2$ is the kernel of the map

$$\partial_2 : \operatorname{Map}(G\times G, \mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{Map}(G\times G\times G, \mathbb{Z}) $$

given by  $\partial_2 (f)(g,h,k)  = f(h,k) - f(gh,k) + f(g,hk) -f(g,h)$, modulo the image of the map $\partial_1: \operatorname{Map}(G , \mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{Map}(G\times G, \mathbb{Z})$ defined by $\partial_1(f)(g,h) = f(h) - f(gh) + f(h)$.

We already know that this cohomology group is zero.  But this says exactly that the set of functions $f:G \times G \to \mathbb{Z}$ expressible as $g(x)-g(xy)+g(y)$ is equal to those functions in the kernel of $\partial_2$.

This is equivalent to Denis Serre's answer above - it may look as if there's a discrepancy, but this is fixable by noting that any such f is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks mt! This is certainly a very suggestive interpretation, and it also has a nice side effect: it indicates clearly how one could generalize the problem!